# Wildfly 26 server Data Base connection leak

Tags: java, connection, wildfly

Deploying Java application on Wildfly 26 server. The application is running properly for sometime. After 2~3 hours I am not able to access the application and getting below error. The DB connections are not establish an of the application.

```
2023-08-09 11:08:43,315 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (default task-3) HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
2023-08-09 11:09:43,317 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2023-08-09 11:09:43,317 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) IJ031012: Unable to obtain lock in 60 seconds: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@3bd631fa
2023-08-09 11:09:43,319 ERROR [com.example.fly.flyadmin.security.SystemUserServiceImpl] (default task-3) Error occurred retrieving a list of SystemUsers : could not prepare statement
2023-08-09 11:09:43,320 ERROR [com.example.fly.flyadmin.security.SpoofAction] (default task-3) com.example.fly.common.exception.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
2023-08-09 11:09:43,320 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) com.example.fly.common.exception.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
2023-08-09 11:09:43,320 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at deployment.flyadmin.war//com.example.fly.flyadmin.security.SystemUserServiceImpl.readAll(SystemUserServiceImpl.java:115)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,320 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at deployment.flyadmin.war//com.example.fly.flyadmin.security.SystemUserServiceImpl.readAllSpoofers(SystemUserServiceImpl.java:155)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at deployment.flyadmin.war//org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at deployment.flyadmin.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at deployment.flyadmin.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at deployment.flyadmin.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at deployment.flyadmin.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at deployment.flyadmin.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at deployment.flyadmin.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
2023-08-09 11:09:43,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)         at deployment.flyadmin.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
```

Still I am getting the error above. Configuration is Java 17, Wildfly 26.1.1, Oracle 19C. For JDBC connection using oracle11.jar. Once I deploy the application it will run for an hour to two, after that even if we don't use the application it stops access.